# Vue v-if resolve Promise - implementing Laravel Gate in Vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to implement Laravel's authorization & policy in Vue, by implementing a mixin which sends a GET request to a controller in the backend.

The problem is the v-if directive is receiving a Promise, which obviously does not resolve

Below is a very simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

The global mixin, auth.js

```js
import axios from "axios"

export default {
    methods: {
        async $can (permission, $model_id) {
            let isAuthorized = false;

            await axios.get(`/authorization?${permission}&${model_id}`)
            .then(function (response) {
                isAuthorized = response.data.isAuthorized
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                isAuthorized = false;
            });

            return isAuthorized;
        }
    }
}
```

The main entry file, app.js

```js
import Auth from '@/auth';

Vue.mixin(Auth);
...
new Vue({...})
```

Component.vue

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="$can('do-this', 12)">
            Show Me
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {}
</script>
```

Is there any way to 'await' the async `$can` operation in v-if? Or am I approaching this from a totally wrong direction?

Comment: *Is there any way to 'await' the async $can operation in v-if? Or am I approaching this from a totally wrong direction?* - no, there's no way. Yes, you are. In case there's a promise await for it on app init, with async component or else. isAuthorized should be a part of the state (usually Vuex) and be separated from $can.

Comment: Thought about that, but probably not possible in this case. On a certain page I might have multiple items with different permissions for the current user, of which I don't know the type and kind of permission ahead of time. My `$can` method 'ideally' handle this as it would be supplied the permission name, model type, and optionally model ID.

Comment: Then you have a problem that needs to be solved in differently. Don't write the logic in a template. Angular supports this, Vue doesn't. You likely to write it in JS, like the answer shows, or some other way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need async/await there because axios returns a promise. I think you can call that function from the created hook. Instead of returning a value, change the related data attribute, and use it in v-if like so:

```
<div v-if="permissions['do-this__12']">

data() {
  return {
    permissions: {
      'do-this__12': false,
      'or-this__13': false,
    },
  }
}

methods: {
  getPermissions() {
    for (const key in this.permissions) {
      this.can(key.split('__')[0], key.split('__')[1])
    }
  },
  can(permission, model_id) {
    axios.get(`/authorization?${permission}&${model_id}`)
      .then(response => {
        this.permissions[`${permission}__${model_id}`] = response.data.isAuthorized
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.permissions[`${permission}__${model_id}`] = false;
      });
  },
}
created() {
  this.getPermissions();
}
```

I didn't try my code, let me know if it fails. BTW, extracting this implementation to a mixin will be a better idea. If you like to do that, just leave "permissions" object in the component and move everything else to the mixin.

But that approach isn't effective when you need multiple API calls for permissions. That's why I think you should pass the whole permissions object to the backend and make the work in the server:

```
iPreferThisBecauseOfSingleAPICall() {
    axios.get(`/authorization`, this.permissions)
         .then(({ data }) => this.permissions = data)
}
```

```
// AuthorizationController

public function index(Request, $request)
{
   $permissions = [];

   foreach($request->all() as $permission) {
     // run your backend code here
   }

   return $permissions;
}
```

One final note, instead of asking for permission each time, loading all permissions at one can be the best idea.

Comment: *You don't need async/await there because axios returns a promise* - why is this a reason to not use async..await? It's supposed to be used with promises, that's its purpose.

Comment: Because he's waiting for only one function, which returns a promise.

Comment: I don't see the relation. `await` is needed to not write `then` explicitly. It's a matter of code consistency. Also, `can` and `getPermissions` have a smell. They don't return a promise and encapsulate asynchronous process, this limits ways in which they can be composed and tested. This can be done on purpose if necessary, but here it looks like a problem that wouldn't exist if async..await were used where it's intended.

Comment: The problem is not async, it's the lack of default value. If it's set false, which should be false based on the original code, everything will solve easily and async will become unnecessary. As you said under the questioın, "no, there's no way". And I showed him a way with a different approach. If it's not good enough for you, let's see your answer.

Comment: My comment refers only to the line that states that this is not the case for await, not to the rest of the answer. I believe it's misleading, especially because the code in the answer that uses with raw promises is potentially troublesome because it doesn't follow good practices that async..await naturally provides.